# Modernizr Browser Feature Detection and Flash Fallback

Tags: html, modernizr, double-click-advertising

I have built an HTML5 creative that will be served via the Google Doubleclick environment. It utilizes CSS3 transforms / 3d animations etc. that aren't supported by IE8/9/10.

I would like to use Modernizr and checked the documentation but couldn't find any info as to how to reference an independent Flash(swf) file as a fallback. I don't mean within the same html document - like when you would hide or display a div, depending on what the browser supports, but instead just having a separate Flash file served?

Ideally I would just upload the swf, along all other HTML5 files into the same directory within the Doubleclick Studio environment, reference the swf via relative path and then have it served to IE8/9/10.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check out the latest version of [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com), which is what powered Modernizr.load